# Can't define VM using ansible virt module

Tags: ansible, libvirt

I'm trying to define a vm using ansible virt module but keep getting an error (details below). When I use *shell* module, vm is defined with no issues so I think I might be missing a library for *virt define* to work properly.

**Working**

```
- name: define vm
  become: yes
  become_user: ubuntu
  shell: virsh define /etc/libvirt/qemu/vsr01-sr1.xml
```

**Not Working**

```
- name: define vm
      become: yes
      become_user: ubuntu  
      virt:
        command: define
        xml: /etc/libvirt/qemu/vsr01-sr1.xml
        uri: 'qemu:///system'
```

**Error**

```
TASK [define vm] ****************************************************************************************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
fatal: [192.168.64.2]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'"}
```

Target is running `python 3.6.9` with following libraries installed previously:

```
apt: ['qemu-kvm', 'libvirt-bin', 'virt-manager', 'virtinst', 'qemu-utils', 'qemu-system-x86', 'sgabios', 'pkg-config', 'libvirt-dev', 'python3-pip']

pip3:['libvirt-python', 'lxml']

Host (MacOS): python 3.7.7, pip3, libvirt, libvirt-python
```

Answer (score 2):

Got the same error. Apparently you cant refer to a direct xml file

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/modules/virt_module.html#virt-module

'XML document used with the define command.
Must be raw XML content using lookup. XML cannot be reference to a file.'